How to change SPUser to SPFieldUserValue in ItemAdding event receiver
There is a field in my list called Authority Name and its type is Person. I am writing ItemAdding event receiver where I want to change this fields value.
For e.g. if user is adding Mike in this field then I want to replace it with John. I have tried both SPUser and SPFieldUserValue but getting error in both.
If I try following where myspuser is a SPUser object then I get error
properties.AfterProperties["Authority_x0020_Name"] = myspuser;

Error

Invalid data has been used to update the list item. The field you are
trying to update may be read only

If I try following where I am trying to conver SPUser to SPFieldUserValue then I get error
SPFieldUserValue myspfielduservalue = new SPFieldUserValue(context.Web, myspuser);

Error

Value does not fall within the expected range

Is it not possible to update Person or Group field in ItemAdding event?

Is this person field is single user or multi-user field?

Single user field

I fixed it by using the following code:
SPFieldUserValue myspfielduservalue = new SPFieldUserValue(context.Web, myspuser.ID + ";#"+ myspuser.LoginName);

properties.AfterProperties["Authority_x0020_Name"] = myspfielduservalue;

